# Entity Framework Foreign Key Queries

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity

I have two tables in my entity framework, objects, and parameters which have a foreign key pointing to the object to which they belong.  I want to populate a tree with all the attributes of a certain object.  So in order to find those I want to do this:

```
   String parentObject = "ParentObjectName";
   var getAttributes = (from o in myDB.ATTRIBUTE
                        where o.PARENT_OBJECT == parentObject
                        select o);
```

However when I try to do this I get an error saying it cannot convert from type OBJECT to string, even though in the database this value is stored as a string.  I have a workaround where I get an instance of the parentObject, then go through every attribute and check whether it's parent_object == parentObjectInstance, but this is much less efficient than just doing 1 query.  Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Which version are you using, EF3.5 or EF4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `PARENT_OBJECT.ToString()` can't be called (implicitly or explicitly) in L2E, but if it just returns a property, you can look at that directly:

```
String parentObject = "ParentObjectName";
var getAttributes = (from o in myDB.ATTRIBUTE
                     where o.PARENT_OBJECT.NAME == parentObject
                     select o);
```

...note the `.NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String parentObject = "ParentObjectName"; 
   var getAttributes = (from o in myDB.ATTRIBUTE 
                        where o.PARENT_OBJECT.ToString() == parentObject 
                        select o);
```

Comment: You could also try this:  'myDB.Attributes.Select(a => a.PARENT_OBJECT.ToString() == parentObject);'

Comment: I tried the .toString() which throws: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Both of those statements throw the same exception =/

Comment: Hmm.  To clarify, you have a one to many table relationship between the object table and the attributes table, correct?  So parent_object is a foreign key?

Comment: Check this thread out, I think it might have your solution.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/19a33909-c532-419b-a533-57e431c0b30b

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Sorry probably should've named the string parentObjectName or something to make it more clear.  But it is 1 to many between those two tables, with PARENT_OBJECT being a foreign key in the attribute table.